# How to use ios-Charts library to display charts in my App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-charts

I am using ios_Charts library by danielgindi.I am using Objective-C to build my app. I have successfully dragged charts.xcodeproj in my project. And i am able to import "MyApp-Swift.h" in my project. But i am not able to understand how to proceed further to use barChart in my app.Please help me on this as I am newbie to iOS. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read this? https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Yes, But when i am using BarChartView, it is giving me an error unknown type name BarChartView.

Comment: Am i missing something?

Comment: @Kaps18 can you add a screenshot of the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error 'unknown type name BarChartView' makes it sound like you haven't set up your view correctly.

Drag a view onto your view controller. Click on the view and select the 'show identity inspector button' and set the class to 'BarChartView':

[image]